# Save accessory checkmarks on uitableview when users loads view multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

So I've implemented a UIViewController with a tableview, and basically it loads as a set of "filters" for my uicollectionview.

Now, when I click on the checkmarks in my tableview, it "filters" my cells accordingly, but now when I reload the view again I want to display the most recent "checkmarks" I've used, or "filters."

I have seen this being implemented with NSUserDefaults, but I have not been able to successfully implement this.

If anyone could help me, that will be greatly appreciated.

**CODE**

**FiltersViewController.m:**

```
#import "FiltersViewController.h"

@interface FiltersViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet *selectedRowObjects;
//@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *filters;

@end

@implementation FiltersViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.selectedRowObjects = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:10];
}

- (IBAction)filtersSelected:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate filtersSelected:self.selectedRowObjects];
}

- (IBAction)cancelFilterSelection:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate filterSelectionCancelled];
}

- (NSString *)getKeyForIndex:(int)index
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"KEY%d",index];
}

- (BOOL) getCheckedForIndex:(int)index
{
    if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:[self getKeyForIndex:index]] boolValue]==YES)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void) checkedCellAtIndex:(int)index
{
    BOOL boolChecked = [self getCheckedForIndex:index];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!boolChecked] forKey:[self getKeyForIndex:index]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"filter" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", indexPath.row];



    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *obj = cell.textLabel.text;

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.selectedRowObjects removeObject:obj];
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.selectedRowObjects addObject:obj];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
@end
```

Comment: You are fetching and setting user defaults in methods that aren't referenced from anywhere else in your code.

Comment: @duci9y ok could you please explain that to me using code? I understand what you are saying

Comment: NSLog your userDefault values (at several points) to see if they are what you expect..

Answer (score 5):

you need to check in cellForRowAtIndexPath also. Write this code in this

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[self getKeyForIndex:indexPath.row]])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

And yes don't forget to call this method in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
[self checkedCellAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Enjoy.

Comment: this didn't work at all. Now what happens is when I load the table view it displays all the check marks every time I open it.

Comment: your requirement is that brother ok but you have to remove nsuserdefault when re load   try this                              [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"pass your key here"];

Comment: Your requirement is to store in NSUserDefault , if you don't use NSUserDefault then it is very easy with Array

Comment: Partially worked. When I unchecked, app restarted checked again.

Answer (score 4):

You did almost everything right. You just need to put your logic for reading the NSUserDefault values (for the checked boxes) in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method. That is the method that draws the UITableViewCells when they are displayed on screen. Something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"filter" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", indexPath.row];

    if ([self getCheckedForIndex:indexPath.row])
    {
        //code to set checkbox
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: this didn't work at all. Now what happens is when I load the table view it displays all the check marks every time I open it.

Comment: I guess I am unclear on the specs. Perhaps you could attach a few screen shots showing exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = ArrayOfObject[indexPath.row];
NSUserDefaults *ud =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if([[ud objectForKey:@"selectedObjectKey "]isEqualToString:ArrayOfObject[indexPath.row]])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
return cell;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented perfectly. You just need to modify you cellForRowAtIndexPath Method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"filter" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", indexPath.row];

BOOL checked = [self getCheckedForIndex:indexPath.row];
   if(checked)
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
   else
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


    return cell;
}
```

Also Call  `[self checkedCellAtIndex:indexPath.row];` from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to save tableView CheckMark with NSUserDefaults

```
    @interface TableViewController (){
    NSArray *TableTitles;
    NSMutableArray *SelectedRows;
}
```

viewDidLoad

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // table view array
    TableTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];

    NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    SelectedRows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[userDef objectForKey:@"SelectedRows"]];
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = TableTitles[indexPath.row];

    NSNumber *obj = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];
    if ([SelectedRows containsObject:obj])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSNumber *obj = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];
    if ([SelectedRows containsObject:obj])
    {
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [SelectedRows removeObject:obj];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }else{
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [SelectedRows addObject:obj];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }

    NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDef setObject:SelectedRows forKey:@"SelectedRows"];
    [userDef synchronize];
}
```

updated ...

i updated all code with a new way , it's the best way to save TableView CheckMarks and it's now easy and efficient, now only one array is used for saving and loading , code reduced too much :)

Answer (score 0):

You should load data in `NSUserDefaults` while call  `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"filter" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", indexPath.row];

    //You should set accessoryType here by NSUserDefaults data
    if ([self getCheckedForIndex:indexPath.row]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to get the current state of the table for the filters when you enter and exit the view.  You need to utilize the `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` to save the current state of the table to your NSUserDefaults, and then use `- (void)viewDidLoad` and `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to set the checkmark when the table reloads.

```
@interface FiltersViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_filterStates;
}

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    filterStates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // get state of your current filters in NSUserDefaults, these should be stored as [NSNumber numberWithBool:]
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    // store all of your filters into your NSUserDefaults as [NSNumber numberWithBool:]
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // get your cell from the table

    BOOL isChecked = [[_filterStates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];

    // set the checkmark based on the current state for this filter
}
```