# UITableView - Check if Cell checkmark

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my UITableView, user can check or not check a Cell. How can I figure out, witch are checked and save this in an Array?

With following code, you can check the cell:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([cell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }
    else {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: You should handle that in the logic of your app...

Comment: You will get help from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25129803/3202193

Answer (score 3):

Don't check for the checkmark as an accessory view of the cells. Cells are being reused and this would mess with your logic.

Instead, keep a mutable set of objects being *presented* by the cells that are currently 'selected' aka checked.

When the user taps a cell you can toggle membership of the presented object in your mutable set and update the checkmark appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

```
//loop through all sections in tableview    
for (int section = 0; section < [tableView numberOfSections]; section++) {
        //loop through all rows in each section
        for (int row = 0; row < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row++) {
            //get the cell based on current index
            NSIndexPath* cellPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
            UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellPath];
            //check cell accessory
            if([cell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
               //cell has checkmark, add to array
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will either not work for offscreen cells that get manually created for this 'counting' purpose if he doesn't have logic for saving the state, or is completely inappropriate logic if he does.

Comment: You're right, I didn't even think about cell reuse.  It's been a while since I've done anything in iOS